# How to convert request query id = '[12eetftt76237,jhgasduyas7657]' to array of elements or array of strings [12eetftt76237,jhgasduyas7657]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, hapi.js

so this is a hapijs, typescript project. I need to send an array of id s as params through request URL.

URL example : localhost:3444/?id='[askjajk78686,ajshd67868]'

I tried split(',') but, the result i get is

```
'[qweqwe121212312,iojqwio78788768]'.split(',');
```

result = ['[qweqwe121212312', 'iojqwio78788768]']

the result have '[' (in it look above result), i need id(qweqwe121212312) with out '['

I need to map through eact element to do some tasks, so i need result as ['asdad32323','zxccscssd33'];

Any ideas ?

Comment: to be precise: my url = localhost:300/?id=[2121dsdsddsd,12121xcas]; - I am getting the request query as a sting '[2121dsdsddsd,12121xcas]' , I need array not string so i tried split(','), But the result includes [ sqare bracket in it ( [ '[213fwfwefwe','jhfs778]' ] , its not correct

Comment: Please do **not** post additional details in the comments - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: The computer can't read your mind; if you want it to remove a prefix from a string first, ask it to remove that prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If the array elements don't include `[` or `]` then you could just replace them and them with empty strings and then split it

`id.replaceAll(']','').replaceAll('[','').split(',')`

But, most likely you need to rethink how you are sending the params. You should encode it as a JSON, so you could simply use `JSON.parse(id)`

Comment: i am new to the node world, any good link or source about "But, most likely you need to rethink how you are sending the params. You should encode it as a JSON, so you could simply use JSON.parse(id)" will be so helpfull,also I will search. Thank you man. tried uvote but i dont have enough score to do it they say

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of brackets with slice, then you can split it as you want.

```
let str = '[qweqwe121212312,iojqwio78788768]'
const res = str.slice(1,-1).split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get elements from your string, you can use regex.

> \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

```js
const valuesString = '[qweqwe121212312,iojqwio78788768]';

const values = valuesString.match(/\w+/g); // get values via regex;

console.log(values[0], values[1])
```